# is there any way to merge sub-array and child sub-array into one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`let arr = [A, B, C, [D, E, F, [G, H, I]]];`

I've tried many array methods but eventually I didn't get expected result. 

I need output like this

`let arr = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I];`

Comment: `let flat = arr.flat(2)`

Comment: or `arr.flat(Infinity)` if you don't know the depth beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```js
const arrays = ["A", "B", "C", ["D", "E", "F", ["G","H", "I"]]];
const merge3 = arrays.flat(2); //The depth level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.
console.log(merge3);
```

Answer (score 0):

> For flatten an n-dimensional array using reduce and concat

```js
function flatArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatArray(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
}



console.log(flatArray(['A', 'B', 'C', ['D', 'E', 'F', ['G', 'H', 'I']]]));
```